# I need to obtain pixel values for each pixel brightness (0-255)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Description:

I'm using python 2.7 and I have packages PIL, pip, pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg-info and Pillow-4.1.1-py2.7.egg-info installed

I am trying to get python to analyze an image and output the pixels 0-255 with its associated pixel values, in the form of a histogram or a list, preferably.

The results im looking for:

0 5

1 6

2 8

3 7

...

...

...

Attempts:

I've tried uninstalling pil, failed
I've installed the package Image
I can't install Pillow till I've uninstalled pil
All this was done on Python command line

Code Attempt 1:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
Image.open('C:\\Users\\tsamimi\\Documents\\BasilIce\\FreqVal\\06.953_UTC-clear basil ice.jpg').load()

im = Image.open('C:\\Users\\tsamimi\\Documents\\BasilIce\\FreqVal\\06.953_UTC-clear basil ice.jpg', 'r')

pix_val = list(im.getdata())

pix_val_flat = [x for sets in pix_val for x in sets]
```

Code attempt 2:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFile

ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True

Image.open('C:\\Users\\abbot\\Documents\\BasilIce\\FreqVal\\06.953_UTC-clear basil ice.jpg').load()

im = Image.open('C:\\Users\\abbot\\Documents\\BasilIce\\FreqVal\\06.953_UTC-clear basil ice.jpg', 'r')

width, height = im.size

pixel_values = list(im.getdata())
```

Output for both code 1,2: `Process finished with exit code 0`

Where did the result go? Is it the lack of indentation?

Thank you

Comment: `Process finished with exit code 0` just means your program ran successfully without any errors. I don't see any `print` statements in your code. What kind of output are you expecting?

Comment: My post above states the result Im looking for, thanks

Comment: What I meant was: In what form are you expecting your output to appear? As a file? In the terminal? I still don't see any print statements in your code.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What does `0 5` on the first line of expected output mean? That the top-left pixel has a zero Red component, 5 for the Green component and you aren't interested in Blue?

Comment: Why is this tagged as opencv when the code just uses PIL?

Comment: The output can be in the form of a file or in the terminal. File would be nice. The 0 reps the pixel value (0-255) and the 5 would represent the brightness value assc. with that pixel value. I need that '5' value.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally worked out what you want - it's a histogram! Luckily that is simple, so starting with this cartoon:

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image

# Load image as greyscale and calculate histogram
im = Image.open('cartoon.jpg').convert('L')
h = im.histogram()

# Print histogram
for idx, val in enumerate(h):
    print(idx,val)
```

**Sample Output**

```
0 41513
1 2362
2 1323
3 1057
4 889
5 780
6 887
7 454
...
...
249 44
250 65
251 119
252 179
253 275
254 246
255 20
```

Note that if you want the histogram for an RGB image, change the third line to:

```
im = Image.open('cartoon.jpg')
```

and you will then get 768 values printed, the first 256 are the red components, then next 256 are the green components and the final 256 are the blue components.

Comment: Just to be certain, that sample output is the brightness values for each pixel in the grayscale image? Also, what does the 'L' after convert indicare? Thank you

Comment: The `L` converts the 3 RGB values of each pixel in the image into a single Lightness (i.e. brightness/greyscale) value for each pixel. Read the results output like this... *"there are 41513 pixels in the image that are pure black (brightness=0), there are 2362 pixels in the image that are almost black (brightness=1)... the last line says there are 20 pixels that are pure white (brightness=255)."*

Comment: So I did ask if there was a way I could put the output in a file or in the form of a graph, with the x axis limit being 0-255 and the y limit be 0-7%. Is there a way to do that? Do you mind editing your response to include that?

Comment: If you saved the above script in a file called `makehist.py` and made it executable with `chmod +x makehist.py`, then you could run it and save the output in a file with `./makehist.py > hist.txt`